# Packages.gz naming convention

Tags: package-management

Can someone provide a script that can fetch package information (name, depends, etc.) from the Packages repository file(s)?

Or can someone tell what the naming convention is for the Packages file?

Let me explain.  When we give the command `apt-get update` it fetches a Packages.gz file from the web which contains each package's information. I need to fetch information for each package from that file.  Or I could use a tutorial link instead.

Note: it is not a homework :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`apt-cache` can be used to query the packages list. To get a full list of all known packages, run `apt-cache dump`.

Generally, you want to get a list of all available packages, and get more information about a certain package.

- `apt-cache pkgnames` - shows all available package names
- `apt-cache show [package]` - shows all known information about package `[package]` (multiple outputs are possible if a package exists in multiple repositorues, like a PPA and the main repos)
- `apt-cache depends [package]` - shows the dependencies for package `[package]`